# scrapy command Crawler(settings) get error: 'Settings' object has no attribute 'update_settings'

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrapy

I am new to Scrapy and python.
I created two spiders and they work OK, when I run them from command line. 
(I use scrapy1.0.3, python 2.7.10)

> `Scrapy crawl spider1  -o res111.csv`

I get data in the csv

know I try to do it from code that I found bellow and I get error

```
 crawler = Crawler(settings)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 32, in __init__
    self.spidercls.update_settings(self.settings)
AttributeError: 'Settings' object has no attribute 'update_settings'
```

I try to find an answer online but didn't find nothing that could help me.

Appreciate any assistance. The code I use:

```
from shopes.spiders.spider1 import MySpider1
from shopes.spiders.spider2 import MySpider2

# scrapy api
from scrapy import signals#, log
from twisted.internet import reactor
from scrapy.crawler import Crawler
from scrapy.settings import Settings
#from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings
import logging
#from twisted.python import log
#import logging
LOG_FILENAME = "log.log"

file = "AAAAA.json" #your results
TO_CRAWL = [MySpider1]


# list of crawlers that are running 
RUNNING_CRAWLERS = []

def spider_closing(spider):
    """Activates on spider closed signal"""
    logging.msg("Spider closed: %s" % spider, level=log.INFO)
    RUNNING_CRAWLERS.remove(spider)
    if not RUNNING_CRAWLERS:
        reactor.stop()

#log.start(logfile = LOG_FILENAME , loglevel=log.DEBUG)
logging.basicConfig(filename=LOG_FILENAME,level=logging.DEBUG)
for spider in TO_CRAWL:
    settings = Settings()
    settings.set("USER_AGENT", "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.134 Safari/537.36")
    settings.set("FEED_FORMAT",'json')
    settings.set("FEED_URI",file)
    settings.set("ITEM_PIPELINES",{ 'pipelines.CustomPipeline': 300})
    settings.set("DOWNLOAD_DELAY",1)
    crawler = Crawler(settings)
    crawler_obj = spider()
    RUNNING_CRAWLERS.append(crawler_obj)

    # stop reactor when spider closes
    crawler.signals.connect(spider_closing, signal=signals.spider_closed)
    crawler.configure()
    crawler.crawl(crawler_obj)
    crawler.start()

# blocks process so always keep as the last statement
reactor.run()
```

[The example code](http://www.codegur.net/33126053/how-can-i-put-all-the-results-of-2-spiders-in-one-xml-with-scrapy)

I changed it  thanks to eLRuLL answer but now I get error:

```
raise error.ReactorNotRestartable()
twisted.internet.error.ReactorNotRestartable
```

Any suggestion?
the update code:
( maybe it will help someone that got the error  `AttributeError: 'Settings' object has no attribute 'update_settings'`)

```
from shopes.spiders.humberrunner import HumberrunnerSpider
from shopes.spiders.upandrunning import UpandrunningSpider

# scrapy api
from scrapy import signals#, log
from scrapy.xlib.pydispatch import dispatcher
from twisted.internet import reactor
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.settings import Settings
#from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings
import logging
#from twisted.python import log
#import logging
LOG_FILENAME = "log.log"

file = "runnerRes.csv" #your results
TO_CRAWL = [UpandrunningSpider , HumberrunnerSpider]


# list of crawlers that are running 
RUNNING_CRAWLERS = []

def spider_closing(spider):
    """Activates on spider closed signal"""
    logging.msg("Spider closed: %s" % spider, level=log.INFO)
    RUNNING_CRAWLERS.remove(spider)
    if not RUNNING_CRAWLERS:
        reactor.stop()


#log.start(logfile = LOG_FILENAME , loglevel=log.DEBUG)
logging.basicConfig(filename=LOG_FILENAME,level=logging.DEBUG)
for spider in TO_CRAWL:
    settings = Settings()
    #settings.set("USER_AGENT", "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.134 Safari/537.36")
    settings.set("FEED_FORMAT",'csv')
    settings.set("FEED_URI",file)
    #settings.set("ITEM_PIPELINES",{ 'pipelines.CustomPipeline': 300})
    settings.set("DOWNLOAD_DELAY",1)
    crawler = CrawlerProcess(settings)
    crawler_obj = spider()
    RUNNING_CRAWLERS.append(crawler_obj)

    # stop reactor when spider closes
    #crawler.signals.connect(spider_closing, signal=signals.spider_closed)
    dispatcher.connect(spider_closing, signal=signals.spider_closed)
    #crawler.configure()
    crawler.crawl(crawler_obj)
    crawler.start()

# blocks process so always keep as the last statement
reactor.run()
```

Comment: please check the [documentation](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html#run-scrapy-from-a-script), looks like you need to use `CrawlerProcess` not `Crawler`

Comment: Hi Ron! Could you please tell us the version of scrapy you are running? Also I have written a [blog post](http://kirankoduru.github.io/python/multiple-scrapy-spiders.html) about how to run multiple scrapers if you want to know how.

Comment: Hi , my scrapy version is 1.0.3

Comment: Thanks for the reply Kiran, I tried your example , and I got error with the log.start, when I removed it I got the same error as I got with the above example.Am I missing something?

Comment: thanks eLRulLL: I changed to CrawlerProcess and it fixed the problem, know I get error  >"crawlerProcess exception no module named pipeline" so it looks like I need to check how to write a pipeline as I want to save my results to file

Comment: I replaced the rows                          `#crawler.signals.connect(spider_closing, signal=signals.spider_closed)
 dispatcher.connect(spider_closing, signal=signals.spider_closed) `  and it solve the pipeline problem know I get                                     `raise error.ReactorNotRestartable()
twisted.internet.error.ReactorNotRestartable`